# Get segno to appear above chord-names in LilyPond

Tags: chords, lilypond, repeats

Problem:  The segno appears between the staff and the chord-names, pushing the chord names up, which makes them hard to read:

[image: Measure of music with a segno above the staff, and chord symbols above the segno.]

I'd like to have the segno appear above the chord names (so that the chord names remain close to the staff). Putting the `\segno` into the `ChordNames` context doesn't produce any mark.  `ChordNames` contexts also don't seem to like `\markup` either (so I can't try the recipes from the documentation).

Code for attached image:

```
\score{
  <<
  \new ChordNames \chordmode{
    f4. ~ f4 bes8 f2. 
  }
  \new Staff {
    \clef "bass"
    \key f \major
    \time 12/8
    f2.\segno f4. f8 c a
  }
  >>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing

```
\time 12/8
f2.\segno f4. ...
```

with

```
\time 12/8
s1*0 \mark \markup{   \musicglyph #"scripts.segno" } 
f2.\segno f4. ...
```

works.  Somehow making the symbol a markup attached to a zero-duration note allows the renderer to push it to the side.   However, some think that the `s1*0` construct is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

Since LilyPond version 2.23, there’s been a repeat structure specifically for *da capo*, *dal segno*, *alla coda*, *al fine*, etc.: `\repeat segno N {…}`.

It works somewhat like the `\repeat volta N {…}` structure, and prints the various repeat symbols automatically.  The segno symbol is placed above the chord names by default.

Details can be found on this page of the documentation: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/long-repeats#segno-repeat-structure

#### Code

```
\version "2.24.1"

\score {
    <<
        \new ChordNames {
            \chordmode {
                R1. |
                \repeat segno 2 {
                    f4. ~ f4 bes8 f2. |
                }
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \clef "bass"
            \key f \major
            \time 12/8
                R1. |
                \repeat segno 2 {
                    f2. f4. f8 c a |
                }
        }
    >>
}
```

**NB**: I’ve put in a rest for the first measure so that it produces a *dal segno*, rather than a *da capo* repeat.

#### Image

[image: Rendering of the above code, showing segno mark above chord symbols.]